# How to pass column value to another column in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the  following jqgrid code, I am creating a link and then trying to pass the bankId values to each row.
ie 
link1
link2

How can I pass the bankId values in fdic column in jqgrid

```
{ name: 'bankId',label: 'bankId', align:'left', width: 10,hidden:true },
{ name: 'fdicNumber', label: 'fdicNumber',width: 70, key: true,
            formatter: "showlink",
                formatoptions: {
                    baseLinkUrl: testUrl,
                    idName: "",
                    addParam: function (options,rowObject) {
                      //  return "clientid="+options.rowid+" ;
                        return "clientid="+options.bankId+" ;
                    }
                }

            },
```

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You use `addParam` defined as function, which in not allowed in old jqGrid versions. Free jqGrid allows to use function, but the function have *one* object parameter `options`. Thus one can use `options.rowData.bankId` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then the usage of `addParam` as function is allowed. The callback function has **one** parameter with properties `cellValue`, `rowid`, `rowData` and `options` (with `formatoptions`). You can fix your code of `addParam` as following:

```
addParam: function (options) {
    return "clientid=" + options.rowData.bankId;
}
```

or

```
addParam: function (options) {
    return "clientid=" + encodeURIComponent(options.rowData.bankId);
}
```

Comment: @Oleg-Thank you i used your first method return "clientid=" + options.rowData.bankId;